# What is the right way to style using css :not with wrap div

Tags: css

The problem I'm having can be better describe in code.

I have some HTML like following

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="slider-wrap">
    <div class="products ">
      <div class="product"></div>
      <div class="product"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="page">
  <div class="products">
      <div class="product"></div>
      <div class="product"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS code look like this,

```
.page {
    clear: both;
    .products {
        .product {
            float: left;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid #ff0000;
            background: green;
        }
    }
}
```

Now these codes results in all the DIVs with ´product´ class to have a background green.

What I'm looking for is, how can I, not apply ´product´ styles for ´slider-wrap´ container. That means, the first page container's product will not be green.

Comment: .page:not(:first-of-type)

Comment: how ever, from answers, you can see that the :not() selector was not the better one  to use ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS selector `>`. What the `>` does is that it calls that CSS function only when its a **direct parent**.

So by assigning `.page > .products` , the css rules you applied will only take place if `.page` is the direct parent of `.products`.

`.slider-wrap` comes in between the `.page` and .`products`, so that particular section won't get affected as `.slider-wrap` is now the direct parent.

You can read more about this at  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator

Try this:

```css
.page {
  clear: both;
}

.page > .products .product {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="slider-wrap">
    <div class="products ">
      <div class="product">1</div>
      <div class="product">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="page">
  <div class="products">
    <div class="product">2</div>
    <div class="product">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice answer with right explanation. I haven't used your answer directly but your explanation of > operator opened up the solution for me. cheers.

Comment: Glad it has helped @Arif.

Answer (score 1):

You  may instead `:not()`, filter only  direct children `>` from the `.page` class:

```
.page {
    clear: both;
   > .products {
        .product {
            float: left;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid #ff0000;
            background: green;
        }
    }
}
```

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/YzKJQmv

Comment: It does solve the isse with my current snippet.
but in real scenario there might be other div wrapped the second ´page´. for example: 

<div class="page">
  <div class="products-wrap">
    <div class="products">
        <div class="product">not a slider-wrap child</div>
        <div class="product">not a slider-wrap child</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

when it does, the solution does not work anymore.

Comment: @arif, then, you need an extra selector to reset the background https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/PoYyJGz , i stil think that the :not() attribute is not usefull since html tree can might also be different once there's 2 level nested and then only one ;)  beside , i do not get why you picked the same answers i gave as a the solution, if mine , posted 17mns earlier, doesn't solve the probleme , what's the difference with the other one ;)

Comment: thanks for your effort :)
I have already solved the problem using direct descendant operator (>). You probably are right. I haven't used :not selector.

Comment: no problem, this is exactly what my answer is , direct child or direct descendant is the exact  same :p nevermind ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can target it using `:first-of-type` to overwrite the styles.

```css
.page {
  clear: both;
}

.page .products .product {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  background: green;
}

.page:first-of-type .products .product {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="slider-wrap">
    <div class="products ">
      <div class="product"></div>
      <div class="product"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="page">
  <div class="products">
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: :first-of-type will not work. I probably have presented the scenario in a simple way. but in reality the layout is not that simple.

Comment: Yes. Question needed an update as it was broad. This was in regard to the last line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead of `:not`

```
.page {
    clear: both;
    .products {
        .product {
            float: left;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid #ff0000;
            background: green;
        }
    }
    .slider-wrap{
        .products {
            .product {
                background: yellow;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand your solution. actually thought of doing this if not found any elegant solution.